# Как красиво вставить в toolbar image button

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть layout toolbar, там есть определенные элементы, при добавлении кнопки, эти элементы съезжают.

Мне нужно прикрутить эту кнопку к самой правой стороне бара(в разметке это кнопка  android:id="@+id/light_button) . Как это сделать, без смещения элементов.

Код разметки:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/autocode_layout_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_layout_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button_toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_textView_mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/autoExpert_layout_mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/text_in_list"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="@string/auto"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_in_list"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:text="@string/expert"/>



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="17dp"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/check"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layout" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/light_button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lightning"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать свойство android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: @KirillStoianov не помогло))

Answer (score 1):

Это часть вашей верстки:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/title_layout_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button_toolbar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="close" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_textView_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/autoExpert_layout_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_grey_500"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="auto"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGold"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="expert"/>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/layout" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/light_button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:src="@color/colorGreen"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленый квадрат - это интересующая вас кнопка, если вы хотите убрать тот отступ справа, то вам нужно изменить контейнер на этот

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/autoExpert_layout_mainToolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/done_button_toolbar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
```

Если я конечно правильно понял вашу задачу